# Autofac module order registration causes objects to be injected with their default instance values (default(T))

Tags: c#, .net-core, autofac

I'm facing a problem with Autofac registrations. In short, if I register the models BEFORE my configuration, when I load the configuration, it works smoothly but, if I register the models AFTER I register the configuration, the configuration models are loaded with their default types (default(T)). Below is the code to reproduce the problem:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

using Autofac;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace AutofacConfigurationTest.CrossCutting
{
    public class ModuleModel : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
        {
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<Cache.Configuration>()
                .As<Cache.IConfiguration>();

            containerBuilder.RegisterType<Repository.Configuration>()
                .As<Repository.IConfiguration>();
        }
    }

    public class ModuleConfiguration : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
        {
            var configurationRoot = new Configuration.Container().ConfigurationRoot;

            containerBuilder.RegisterInstance(configurationRoot).As<IConfigurationRoot>();

            containerBuilder
                .RegisterInstance(configurationRoot.GetSection(Cache.Configuration.Name)
                    .Get<Cache.Configuration>()).As<Cache.IConfiguration>();

            containerBuilder
                .RegisterInstance(configurationRoot.GetSection(Repository.Configuration.Name)
                    .Get<Repository.Configuration>()).As<Repository.IConfiguration>();
        }
    }

    public class Container
    {
        public IContainer Kernel { get; }

        public Container()
        {
            var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // uncomment the line below to make it work //
            containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new ModuleModel()); // if we register the models here, before the configuration, the configuration works properly //

            containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new ModuleConfiguration());

            // comment the line below to make it work //
            containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new ModuleModel()); // if we register the models here, after the configuration, the configuration cannot load the data //

            Kernel = containerBuilder.Build();
        }
    }
}

namespace AutofacConfigurationTest.Configuration
{
    public class Container
    {
        private const string ConfigurationFile = "AppSettings.json";

        public Container()
        {
            ConfigurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile(ConfigurationFile).Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot ConfigurationRoot { get; }
    }
}

namespace AutofacConfigurationTest.Cache
{
    public enum Engine
    {
        None,
        Default
    }

    public interface IConfiguration
    {
        Engine Engine { get; set; }
        int Duration { get; set; }
        string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }

    public class Configuration : IConfiguration
    {
        public const string Name = "Cache";

        public Engine Engine { get; set; }
        public int Duration { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace AutofacConfigurationTest.Repository
{
    public enum Engine
    {
        None,
        LiteDb
    }

    public interface IConfiguration
    {
        Engine Engine { get; set; }
        string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }

    public class Configuration : IConfiguration
    {
        public const string Name = "Repository";

        public Engine Engine { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace AutofacConfigurationTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static IContainer _container;

        private static void RegisterServices() => _container = new CrossCutting.Container().Kernel;

        private static void DisposeServices()
        {
            if (_container != null &&
                _container is IDisposable disposable)
                disposable.Dispose();
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                RegisterServices();

                // the following objects will be have a default(T) instance
                // if the in the Autofac modules the Model is registered AFTER the Configuration

                var cacheConfiguration = _container.Resolve<Cache.IConfiguration>();
                var repositoryConfiguration = _container.Resolve<Repository.IConfiguration>();

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                DisposeServices();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a second question for you: I use the interfaces to force the contract in my models. In short, these interfaces are NEVER injected anywhere, it's just to make easier the maintenance for me. Should I remove the DI/IoC for these models or is there any reason to keep the models registration in the container?

Comment: `containerBuilder
                .RegisterInstance(configurationRoot.GetSection(Cache.Configuration.Name)
                    .Get<Cache.Configuration>()).As<Cache.IConfiguration>();` Explain what you expect that code to do if `Cache.Configuration` is **not** registered yet. Why might that impact the order in which you need to register things?

Comment: @mjwills, that's my question, I want to know if I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: @rmszc81 what do you mean by "default(T)" ? Since your objects are reference types, default of a reference type is always `null`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observed difference in behavior that now depends on the sequence of module registration, is due to the fact that both modules are registering services keyed to `Cache.IConfiguration` and `Repository.IConfiguration`. Therefore, the last module to be registered will "win".

When `ModuleModel` is registered last it will override any previous registration of the two configuration interfaces, and resolution will yield instances of `Cache.Configuration` and `Repository.Configuration`.

If `ModuleConfiguration` is registered last, resolution will yield instances provided by the `configurationRoot` object.

Inferring your intent from the two modules, since `ModuleConfiguration` registrations are actually trying to resolve `Cache.Configuration` and `Repository.Configuration`, `ModuleModel` must register these types *keyed to those types* instead of keyed to the interfaces. You do that using `.AsSelf()` instead of `.As<some interface>()`. Read more about `AsSelf` [here](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html).